# BadRequest in SDL2 with WSL2

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

With this minimal example I have a `BadRequest` error:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) abort();

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "An SDL2 window",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640,
        480,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
    );
    if(window == NULL) abort();

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(
        window,
        -1,
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC
    );
    if(renderer == NULL) abort();

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

The error is the following

```
$ g++ $(sdl2-config --cflags) foo.cpp $(sdl2-config --libs)
$ ./a.out
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (X_GLXVendorPrivate)
  Serial number of failed request:  197
  Current serial number in output stream:  198
```

It seems the issue appears at the `SDL_CreateRenderer` function. Creating the window works which confirms my X server works too.